# No Module Named 'googleapiclient' when running in PyCharm

Tags: python

When I run the program in Sublime it works fine but today I installed PyCharm, tried to run it there and got this error. I tried to do pip install google-api-python-client but it didn't help. I am new to PyCharm and maybe I am missing something.

```
C:\Users\claud\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\claud\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\samanthamain.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\claud\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\samanthamain.py", line 5, in <module>
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image]

Comment: are u using virtual environment?

Answer (score 3):

According to the output, your interpreter is `C:\Users\claud\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe`, i.e. your project is set up to use a virtual environment.

You probably installed the package with `pip install` without activating the virtual environment in your console, which installed it in the global environment, so it is not visible from the virtual one used by your project.

You can install the package in the virtual environment in the following ways:

1. call `pip install` for the virtual environment by specifying the full path to the environment's interpreter:

```
> C:\Users\claud\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install <package>
```

2. activate the virtual environment, then run `pip install` as usual:

```
> C:\Users\claud\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
(venv) > pip install <package>
```

3. use PyCharm's features:
   `File` > `Settings...` > `Project: <your project>` > `Python Interpreter` > the **+** button on the right.

Comment: In the virtual environment? How do I do that? I tried copy and paste in command prompt but it return "The syntax of the command is incorrect"

Comment: By command prompt you mean `cmd.exe`, right? Did you replace `<package>` with the actual name of your package?

Comment: The only two packages I have are pip and setup tools, see image, what should I do?

Comment: Click the **+** button on the right, then type in the name of your package, then there should be an option to install it. Under the hood this will actually just run a `pip install` command.

Comment: Thank you. It works, I have found the packages needed.!!!!

Answer (score 1):

pycharm creates an virtual enviroment By default. In Pycharm google-api-python-client is not installed. Try to install google-api-python-client in pycharm.

Comment: How do I do that?